# How to filter pandas dataframe by time

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter based my df by time. While reading the csv file , I have parsed 'S2Date' column as dates. For s2Time , I have used `df['S2Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["S2Time"])`  so that its of the format timestamp. Now I need to find out or filter the df by time alone , i.e find records between 9am to 12 noon, or considering below df between 15:00 to 16:15 like that.

How can I achieve that ? I was able to filter by dates but by time I am having issues. Can any body assist or point me to the right place to learn abt it ?

MY DF:

```
    S2Saleid        S2Date       S2Time 
0   180519011       2019-05-18  2020-08-13  15:15:00    
1   180519012       2019-05-18  2020-08-13  15:38:00    
2   180519013       2019-05-18  2020-08-13  15:47:00    
3   180519014       2019-05-18  2020-08-13  16:21:00    
4   180519014       2019-05-18  2020-08-13  16:21:00
```

Comment: Could you please add an executable df sample?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pandas `between_time` method. Either set the datetime column as index before filtering by time:

```
df.index = df['S2Time']
df.between_time('15:00', '16:15')

# Out:
#                       S2Saleid      S2Date              S2Time
# S2Time                                                        
# 2020-08-13 15:15:00  180519011  2019-05-18 2020-08-13 15:15:00
# 2020-08-13 15:38:00  180519012  2019-05-18 2020-08-13 15:38:00
# 2020-08-13 15:47:00  180519013  2019-05-18 2020-08-13 15:47:00
```

Or set the index on-the-fly to avoid overwriting the input-df:

```
df.set_index('S2Time').between_time('15:00', '16:15').reset_index()

# Out:
#                S2Time   S2Saleid      S2Date
# 0 2020-08-13 15:15:00  180519011  2019-05-18
# 1 2020-08-13 15:38:00  180519012  2019-05-18
# 2 2020-08-13 15:47:00  180519013  2019-05-18
```

Answer (score 0):

Following also works,

```
time1 = pd.to_datetime('2020-08-13  15:00:00').strftime('%H:%M')
time2 = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01  16:15:00').strftime('%H:%M')
df.loc[(df['S2Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M') > time1 ) & (df['S2Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M') < time2)]
```

Comment: But this only allows for selecting specific dates, requires 3 lines of codes and is roughly 4 times slower than my on-the-fly approach.

Comment: @Scotty1- yes sir, indeed your code is fast and requires less time than mine. But I provided alternate solution, I am too new to pandas.

Comment: Yep, that's true and it is a valid solution. :)

Comment: @Scotty1- yes sir no doubt in that. Have a nice day : )